# How do i get the state value which I have stored in the Child component to the Parent component in React without button OnClick events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component which i call from the Parent and within the child component, i set state and get a specific value which is then stored within a state value. Now, how do i get the value from there and read it in the Parent component without using an onClick event ?

Here's my code snippet:

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
import Child from "../Child"
     const Parent = () => {
        ...
        ...
        
        return(
        ...
        ...
        <Child />
    );
        };
        export default Parent
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
    function Child (props) {
    ...
    ...
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("sample")
    ...
    ...
    return(
    ...
    ...
    );


}
export default Child
```

As you can see above, I initialize a state variable and assign "sample" to "**query**"
How can I get this "query" readable within the **Parent Component** ? I don't want to use an  *Onclick* event, so please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the useState in parent and pass it down to child

```
 const Parent = () => {
   const [query, setQuery] = useState("sample")

    ...
    ...
    
    return(
    ...
    ...
    <Child query={query} setQuery={setQuery}/>
);
```

child

```
 function Child ({query,setQuery }) {
```

Comment: When i do a console log of this, I get an object which does not seem to have the value passed from Parent. Thoughts ? Am i making some mistake ?